# Azure blob create using Rest API python signature error

Tags: python, azure, rest, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I am trying to create blob file using Python code using shared key, but it is failing and below is the details

Note: we cannot use azure blob python sdk due to storage vendor we must use sharedkey

Python code:

```
import requests
import datetime
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64
storage_account_name = '<my-storage-account>'
storage_account_key = 'xxxxxxx'
# Define the container name and blob name
container_name = 'mycontainer5226'
blob_name = "test2"

# Set the request method and version
REQUEST_METHOD = 'PUT'
REQUEST_VERSION = '2020-04-08'

# Set the request date
REQUEST_DATE = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')

CANONICALIZED_HEADERS = f'x-ms-date:{REQUEST_DATE}\nx-ms-version:{REQUEST_VERSION}\n'


# Set the canonicalized resource string
CANONICALIZED_RESOURCE = f'/{storage_account_name}/{container_name}/'

REQUEST_DATE = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')
data = "test 1 23 file content"
Content_Length = str(len(data))
VERB = 'PUT'
Content_Encoding = ''
Content_Language = ''
Content_MD5 = ''
Content_Type = 'text/plain'
Date = ''
If_Modified_Since = ''
If_Match = ''
If_None_Match = ''
If_Unmodified_Since = ''
Range = ''
CanonicalizedHeaders = CANONICALIZED_HEADERS
CanonicalizedResource = CANONICALIZED_RESOURCE

# \'PUT\n\n\n22\n\ntext/plain\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:Fri, 24 Feb 2023 07:58:30 GMT\nx-ms-meta-m1:v1\nx-ms-meta-m2:v2\nx-ms-version:2020-04-08\n/blobmediapedevwus2/mycontainer5226/test2\

STRING_TO_SIGN = (VERB + '\n' + Content_Encoding + '\n' + Content_Language + '\n' +
                Content_Length + '\n' + Content_MD5 + '\n' + Content_Type + '\n' +
                Date + '\n' + If_Modified_Since + '\n' + If_Match + '\n' +
                If_None_Match + '\n' + If_Unmodified_Since + '\n' + Range + '\n' +
                CanonicalizedHeaders + CanonicalizedResource).encode('utf-8').strip()
print(STRING_TO_SIGN)

signed_string = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(base64.b64decode(storage_account_key), msg=STRING_TO_SIGN, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest()).decode()

headers = {
    'x-ms-date' : REQUEST_DATE,
    'x-ms-version' : REQUEST_VERSION,
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
    'Content-Length': Content_Length,
    'x-ms-blob-type': "BlockBlob",
    'x-ms-meta-m1': "v1",  
    'x-ms-meta-m2': "v2",  
    'Authorization' : ('SharedKey ' + storage_account_name + ':' + signed_string)
}

url = ('https://' + storage_account_name + f'.blob.core.windows.net/{container_name}/{blob_name}')


r = requests.put(url, headers = headers, data=data)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.content)
```

below is the string_to_sign:

```
\'PUT\n\n\n22\n\ntext/plain\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:Fri, 24 Feb 2023 08:03:17 GMT\nx-ms-meta-m1:v1\nx-ms-meta-m2:v2\nx-ms-version:2020-04-08\n/blobmediapedevwus2/<storage-account>/test2\

  b'PUT\n\n\n22\n\ntext/plain\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:Fri, 24 Feb 2023 08:03:17 GMT\nx-ms-version:2020-04-08\n/<storage-name>/mycontainer5226/'
```

Actual server signature:

```
b'\xef\xbb\xbf<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.\nRequestId:262e0db6-201e-0010-651c-482d3a000000\nTime:2023-02-24T06:51:30.2303424Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>The MAC signature found in the HTTP request \'3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: \'PUT\n\n\n22\n\ntext/plain\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-blob-type:BlockBlob\nx-ms-date:Fri, 24 Feb 2023 06:51:27 GMT\nx-ms-meta-m1:v1\nx-ms-meta-m2:v2\nx-ms-version:2020-04-08\n/<storage account>/mycontainer5226/test2\'.</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>'
```

seems there could be some issue during constructing signature

Answer (score 0):

Please change the following line of code:

```
Content_Type = ''
```

to

```
Content_Type = 'text/plain'
```

I also noticed that your `CANONICALIZED_RESOURCE` does not include the container name. Please make sure to add the blob container name there.

Comment: i update again same issue, i updated recently tried code, container name and blob file i used

Comment: Please print STRING_TO_SIGN and the updated error message in your post. I believe the issue is with mismatched values for STRING_TO_SIGN.

Comment: Also, please try by removing “ \nrestype:blob” from CANONICALIZED_RESOURCE.

Comment: Thanks for updating. Please add the blob name to `CANONICALIZED_RESOURCE`. It should be something like: `CANONICALIZED_RESOURCE = f'/{storage_account_name}/{container_name}/{blob_name}'`

Comment: I added that and tried, no luck

Comment: Please edit your question and include the updated values for string to sign and the error message.